# How can i set my app is supported with all Android devices ? - Ionic-v3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

yesterday I upload my ionic app on google play store but there showing **9751** **Supported Android Device** only what should I do for all device support for my app…any help, please.

I build the ionic app using this commend: **ionic Cordova build android --prod --release**

and I added this in the config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />    
</platform>
```

I have showing like this Supported Android Devices: 9751
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your settings and [Android developers Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#Platform) you are supporting 99.4% of android devices out there, You can bring down you min and target SDK supported to lower versions of android, but:

1. You will lose the higher end devices
2. It is not suggested, especially less than 14 as lots of design elements have changed and memory management libraries have changed.
3. If you change your target SDK in this level, after all the coding and building has finished you have to go and update your gradle libraries, which will be opening the door to lots of problems.
4. Bringing down your minimum sdk version, you will have run-time problems with older devices.

So my suggestion, keep it safe, don't change anything.